# Select Specific Column from a Linked Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following C# code to select a column from a table that is on a linked server:

```
        var query2 = $@"select [FileName] from [AMS_H2H].[H2H].[dbo].[FileReconciliation] where ProductCode = @productCode";
        LayZConnection(); //make the db connection
        var candidates = _dbConnection.Query<int>(query2, new { productCode = "ACHDH" });
```

When running it, I get the following error:

```
"Input string was not in a correct format."
```

If my query is instead the following, where I select all columns, it works:

```
var query2 = $@"select * from [AMS_H2H].[H2H].[dbo].[FileReconciliation]
```

What is the correct format to select just the FileName. Btw, the first query works fine from MSSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying a type of `int` in `Query<int>`, which will cause Dapper to try and map the result of the query to an integer, however your query is returning a filename in `select [FileName]`, which would suggest that it is a string.

Changing the type `Query<string>` should solve the issue.

More information on Dapper's Query method is available in Dapper's [documentation](https://dapper-tutorial.net/query)

Comment: @Scott if this solves your problem, check the checkmark on the left side of the answer.